# Keep only the strings in between quotes in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++, I use the expression `(?<=").*(?=")` to find all strings in between quotes. It would the seem rather trivial to be able to only keep those results. However, I cannot find an easy solution for this.

I think the problem is that Notepad++ is not able to make multiple selections. But there must be some kind of workaround, right? Perhaps I must invert the regex and then find/replace those results to end up with the strings I want.

For example:

```
blablabla "Important" blabla
blabla "Again important" blablabla
```

I want to keep:

```
Important
Again important
```

Comment: The three answers posted so far all agree that you need to capture the part you want to keep, and this is done by grouping it with parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no great solution for this and depending on your use case I would recommend writing a quick script that actually uses your first expression and creates a new file with all of the matches (or something like this).  However, if you just want something quick and dirty, [this expression](http://regex101.com/r/aJ1nP5) should get you started:

```
[^"]*(?:"([^"]*)")? 
\1\n
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^"]*         # 0+ non-" characters
(?:           # Start non-capturing group
  "           # " literally
    (         # Start capturing group
      [^"]*   # 0+ non-" characters
    )         # End capturing group
  "           # " literally
)?            # End non-capturing group AND make it optional
```

The reason the optional non-capturing group is used is because the end of your file may very well not have a string in quotes, so this isn't a necessary match (we're more interested in the first `[^"]*` that we want to remove).

Comment: On the plus side, your explanation is beautiful!  I wish I had your regex expertise.  On the minus side, the string does not seem to work in Notepad++ ... the results are wierd, arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. You're right though, that using Notepad++ isn't the road to travel in this case, so I've written a short AutoIt script that takes input from the clipboard and creates a file using the regex pattern I mentioned. Much simpler. :)

Comment: Glad I could nudge you in the right direction regardless of if the expression worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be certain from your post, but  <strike>I think you may want</strike> : **SEE BELOW**

```
<(?<=")(.*)(?=")
```

The part you keep will be captured as `\2`.

```
(?<=")(.*)(?=")
  \1   \2  \3
```

Your original regex string uses parentheses to group characters for evaluation.  Parentheses ALSO group characters for capturing.  That is what I added.

### Update:

The regex pattern you provided doesn't seem to work correctly.  Won't this work?

```
\"(.*)\"
```

`\1` now captures the content.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I updated my post with an example. Does your regex then match the inverse of what I want to keep?

Comment: @Sam -- Notepad++ has a less-standard implementation of regex.  Answer stands after testing.

Comment: My regex is rather, um, dull compared with the other examples here.  I think Notepad++ handles newlines funny, allows for a more lazy approach.  Hope the poster will let us in on what finally worked best.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
[^"\r\n]+"([^"]+)"[^"\r\n]+
```

And replace with `$1`. The above regex assumes there will be only 2 double quotes in each line.

`[^"]+` matches non-quote characters.

`[^"\r\n]+` matches non-quote, non newline characters.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB2fQ9)

Comment: I accepted the other answer, mainly because it doesn't assume that there's a double quote in every line. :)